# How to define this JSON as a JAVA Object

Tags: java, json

I'm receiving the following JSON:

```
[
    669124,
    [
        [
            40135,
            5,
            0.68395602
        ],
        [
            40134,
            1,
            0.03737
        ]
    ]
]
```

How can I turn this into a JAVA Object?

Comment: While an online json validator does validate that json as valid, it doesn't feel like json.  BUT, to answer your question, look into a library called [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson).  To generate the classes that get serialized take a peek at [jsonschema2pojo.org](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).  However that website did not like the inputted json.

Comment: Personally, I would create a class with jackson which is a list of something. This something, has a custom serializer/deserializer that for each instance checks whether is a number or a list. If it's a list, it recursively calls itself to parse. I don't think you have any other choice here.

Comment: How would _you_ describe this object in pseudocode? Because a literal desrialization would just be an array of Objects containing an Integer and an array of int[]. pretty meaningless structure

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
public class Outer {
   private int field1;
   private List<Inner> field2;
}

public class Inner {
   private int field1;
   private int field2;
   private double field3;
}
```

And then you just parse the json and read them into these classes?

Comment: I don't think the structure is static as you described it.

Comment: This should be able to satisfy the requirement described by the JSON sample. The actual parsing code... left as an exercise to the reader. Via Jackson, or "by hand" via JSONObject or whatever. @MatteoNNZ - it was too long for a comment, but this is what this answer does. not really an answer, but more a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: This looks fine, but, how do I now parse this with ObjectMapper lets say?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this particular JSON is that it is a list of different types.  The first element is a number (int), the second is a 2-dimensional array of numbers, some ints and some doubles.

So if you tried to parse this to a custom Java object, you would get at best `List<Object>`, or just `Object`.

I believe you want to parse it into a JSON tree.  There are several libraries, Jackson is the most popular by far.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

public class JsonTest {
    String JSON = "[\n" +
        "    669124,\n" +
        "    [\n" +
        "        [\n" +
        "            40135,\n" +
        "            5,\n" +
        "            0.68395602\n" +
        "        ],\n" +
        "        [\n" +
        "            40134,\n" +
        "            1,\n" +
        "            0.03737\n" +
        "        ]\n" +
        "    ]\n" +
        "]";
    
    @Test
    public void testJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode doc = om.readTree(JSON);
    
        assertThat(doc.isArray(), is(true));
        JsonNode element1 = doc.get(0);
        assertThat(element1.isInt(), is(true));
        assertThat(element1.asInt(), is(669124));
    
        JsonNode element2 = doc.get(1);
        assertThat(element2.isArray(), is(true));
    
        assertThat(element2.get(0).get(0).intValue(), is(40135));
        assertThat(element2.get(0).get(1).intValue(), is(5));
        assertThat(element2.get(0).get(2).doubleValue(), is(0.68395602));
    
        assertThat(element2.get(1).get(0).intValue(), is(40134));
        assertThat(element2.get(1).get(1).intValue(), is(1));
        assertThat(element2.get(1).get(2).doubleValue(), is(0.03737));
    }
}
```